# LinkButton in GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem and not getting why is it so. I have a grid view and it contains some 10,000 rows without any pagination. For each Row I have a Edit LinkButton n the TemplateField. On the click of this edit LB the control should go to some Edit Page. The problem here is that after clicking on the LB the page is taking lots of time. On the other hand if I am doing pagination in the GridView and assgning page size = 10 then it is loading very fast. Can anyone please tell me what is the reason. I cant have the pagination for this gridView

Regards,

Vikram

Comment: how are you assigning the Edit server-side event? Some could would help.

Comment: I am not sure so i post it as comment not answer but phsical page size may affect yours performance. If you send back this large page to server just for edit one row then I would reccomend take a look on AJAX.

Comment: Why is paging not an option? You could provide some search-, filter and sorting capabilities for the Grid. That would be better (in my opinion) than to bother the user with a huge response time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView consumes a lot of ViewState.

if you are using other page for editing, maybe you should use Repeater instead of Gridview, and instead of the LinkButton just an Hyperlink with url `EditPage.aspx?id={something}`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the viewstate of the grid?? I think that should sort out the issue.